# Custom URL Routing in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am currently learning ruby on rails with 3.0

I have created a post table with a column called friendly

Instead of using /post/:id I want to use /post/:friendly

meaning a URL will look like /post/post-title instead of /post/1

I have the controller framed properly with this code.

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:friendly])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render :json => @post }
  end
end
```

But I am not sure how to change routes.rb to implement this change.

Right now it just says

```
resources :post
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? What advantage do you gain from calling your id column friendly?

Comment: I updated the post to explain better I want the URL to look like /post/post-title instead of /post/1

Comment: This is commonly done for SEO and overall better user experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use to_param method on the model http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param

If you keep object ID inside of the friendly, ex 1-some-name, 2-some-other-name you will not have to do anything else. Rails will strip id from the string and will use it to find your object. If you don't, you will have to change your controllers to use find_by_friendly(params[:id]) instead of find(params[:id])

Another alternative is to use a gem like https://github.com/norman/friendly_id to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the format of the id variable on find, you can change the route as follows

```
resources :post, :except => find do
  # Change the find to accept an id that's alphanumeric, but you can change 
  # this regex to whatever you need.
  get 'find', :on => :member, :constraints => { :id => /[a-zA-Z]*/ }
end
```

then, to get the post in posts#find, you need to do

```
Post.find_by_friendly(Params[:id])
```

One problem is that this will break the helper paths - eg `post_path(@post)` will need to become `post_path(:id => @post.friendly)`

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints